# Yum freezes on 'Loading mirror speeds' or 'Setting package sacks'

Tags: linux, centos, yum

```
[root@LibertysLastArmy ~]# sudo yum -v update
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Config time: 0.067
Yum Version: 3.2.22
Setting up Package Sacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile


Exiting on user cancel
[root@LibertysLastArmy ~]# su root
[root@LibertysLastArmy ~]# su
[root@LibertysLastArmy ~]# su root
[root@LibertysLastArmy ~]# yum -v update
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Config time: 0.053
Yum Version: 3.2.22
Setting up Package Sacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile


Exiting on user cancel
[root@LibertysLastArmy ~]# yum --noplugins -v update
Config time: 0.076
Yum Version: 3.2.22
Setting up Package Sacks


Exiting on user cancel
```

This happens whenever I attempt to use yum. I've tried using yum clear all,

I've tried all of:

su -c 'rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db*'
su -c 'rpm --rebuilddb'
su -c 'yum check-update'

and varients on these. Nothing has fixed it so far.
I have also tried rebooting the VPS with no success.

It's currently running CentOS 5.6 (Final). Any help would be appreciated. I'm aiming to install GCC ultimately, as I lack a compiler for the gcc source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How much memory do you have on the VPS and what processes are running? Yum doesn't run on VPS with low memory. It'll die.